# Возможно ли реализовать таск, чтобы stylus компилировался в css и это было синхронизовано с Browser Sync?

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp4

Помогите с таском в gulp, нужно чтобы в watch компилировался styl в css. Допустим я меняю размер шрифта в stylus, он компилируется в css и browsersync обновляет страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использует `gulp@^4.2.0`, `gulp-stylus@^2.7.0` и `browser-sync@^2.26.7`

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var stylus = require("gulp-stylus");
var browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
paths = {
css: "src/css",
stylus: "src/stylus/**/*.styl"
};
gulp.task('stylus',async () => {
    await gulp.src([paths.stylus])
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"));
});
gulp.task('serve', async () => {
    browsersync.init({server:{baseDir: "./src"}});
});
gulp.task('reload', async () => {
    browsersync.reload();
});
gulp.task('watch', async () => {
    await gulp.watch([paths.stylus], gulp.series('stylus', 'reload'));
    await gulp.watch(['src/index.html'], gulp.series('reload'));
});
exports.default = gulp.series('stylus', 'serve', 'watch');
```

src/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylus.css" >
</head>
<body>
<p>123</p>
</body>
</html>
```

src/stylus/stylus.styl

```
p
  color #f0f
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно не могу разобраться в чем проблема, можете пожалуйста, если вас не затруднит, подкорректировать мой gulpfile. Вот ссылка: https://github.com/ko7ovz/gulp

Comment: @ЛеонидКотов https://github.com/ko7ovz/gulp/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L14, вы не должны добавлять `.stylus`